# How to check if a key in the User dictionary changed?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I'm wondering if there's a way to track changes of state of a key in the user dictionary defaults.

I don't need to check if it's true or false, I just need to know if it changed.

Here's my scenario:
I have an iAP product that unlocks some feature, and I want these features to be available as soon as they are purchased, without rebooting the app or loging out.

So I implemented the willAppear method on the view that has the features, to check through a key if purchase was made.

The problem with this is that if the key is true (purchased done) it will perform several tasks, but I don't need to perform this tasks EVERY time a user purchased the iAP product use the app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use KVO (Key Value Observer) for this.

If you want to detect changes with specic key the use :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self
                                        forKeyPath:@"YOUR_KEY_HERE"
                                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                           context:NULL];
```

and if want to detect changes whenever NSuserdefauls any key is changed..

Using    `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` you can detect when any change will be done in the key value.

So firstly add Observer :    `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];`

and then detect using :

```
- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
  // Get the user defaults
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[notification object];

  NSLog(@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"YOUR_KEY"]);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This will get called with any change in user defaults, not just with the desired key.